# Problem executing "ionic cordova run android" Unexpected token in JSON at position 0

Tags: ionic-framework

I had an Ionic app and when I try to execute **ionic cordova run android** I get the next error

ionic run ionic\update.json: Unexpected token   in JSON at position 0

Answer (score 0):

I just went to C:\Users\MyUser\ .ionic\ and delete the **update.json** file and it works!